# Why do my errors say String cannot be converted to String[] and int to int[] as well as some others?

Tags: java, methods

My program has some errors that I can't seem to fix. When I run my program there are 11 to be exact.

The main errors I'm struggling with is on line 8 it says String cannot be converted to String[].
This is the line where it says

> `String[] empLastName="";`

I'm also struggling with one on line 9 that says int cannot be converted to int[]
This is the line where it says

> `int[] workStartTime=0, workEndTime=0, totalTimeWorked=0;`

And the error on line 47 that says bad operand types for binary operators '+'
This line is

> `totalTimeWorked=(totalTimeWorked+hoursWorked[i]);`

The program itself is supposed to prompt 10 employees for their

> `last name`
>
> `what time they started their work`

(The time must entered by hour, then minute in military time. For ex., if they start work at 2:20 the user should enter 14 for the hour and 20 for the minute)
 `

> `what time they finished work`

(also formatted like start time).

I'm assuming all data is entered correctly, that the employee finished work after they started, and that both times are for the same day.

The program will determine how many hours each employee worked that day.

It will output a well formatted report listing 
`

> `all of the employees`
>
> `along with the amount of time they worked`

(listed as hours and minutes),

also it should output

> `the average amount of time worked`
>
> `their last name`

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is what I've written-

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeTime 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String[] empLastName="";
        int[] workStartTime=0, workEndTime=0, totalTimeWorked=0;
        String[] empLastNameArray= new String[empLastNameArray.length];
        int[] workStartTimeArray= new int[workStartTimeArray.length];
        int[] workEndTimeArray= new int[workEndTimeArray.length];
        int[] avgHoursWorked= new int[avgHoursWorked.length];

        readEmployeeData(empLastName, workStartTime, workEndTime);
        determineHoursWorked(workStartTime, workEndTime, totalTimeWorked);
        determineAverageHoursWorked(workStartTime, workEndTime);
        writeHeadings();
        printEmployeeInformation(empLastName, workStartTime, workEndTime);
    }

    public static void readEmployeeData(String[] empLastName, int[] workStartTime, int[] workEndTime)
    {

        System.out.println("enter how many students you would like to get the information");


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your last name.");
            empLastName[i]=input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter your work start time.");
            workStartTime[i]=input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter your work end time.");
            workEndTime[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static double[] determineHoursWorked(int[] workStartTime, int[] workEndTime, int[] totalTimeWorked)
    {
        double[] hoursWorked= new double[hoursWorked.length];
        for(int i=0; i<hoursWorked.length; i++)
            hoursWorked[i]= workEndTime[i]-workStartTime[i];
        for(int i=0; i<hoursWorked.length; i++)
        {
            totalTimeWorked=(totalTimeWorked+hoursWorked[i]);
        }
        return hoursWorked;
    }

    public static double[] determineAverageHoursWorked(int[] workStartTime, int[] workEndTime)
    {
        double[] avgHoursWorked= new double[avgHoursWorked.length];
        for(int i=0; i<avgHoursWorked.length; i++)
            avgHoursWorked[i]= (totalTimeWorked/10);
        return avgHoursWorked;
    }

    public static void writeHeadings()
    {
        System.out.printf("%s%25s%13s%16s\n\n", "Employees", "Amount of time worked", "Average amount of time worked");
    }

    public static void printEmployeeInformation(String[] empLastName, int[] hoursWorked, int[] avgHoursWorked);
    {
        for(int i=0; i<empLastName.length; i++)
            System.out.printf("%-20s%9d%13.2f%16.2f\n", empLastName[i], hoursWorked[i], avgHoursWorked[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `""` is not an array, so `String[] empLastName="";` makes no sense, it should either be `String empLastName="";` or `String[] empLastName={""};` depending on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: `int[] workStartTime=0, workEndTime=0, totalTimeWorked=0;` ... See previous comment

Comment: `totalTimeWorked` is an array; `int[] totalTimeWorked`, so `totalTimeWorked + hoursWorked[i]` makes no sense, what are you trying to add?

Comment: Focus on getting one part of the problem working, before trying to move onto the next, for example, try getting the employee's last name from the user.  Once you have that figure out how to get the work time, etc...

Answer (score 0):

as @Madprogramer says your problem is define arrays and set values i recommend see  [this link](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/) about how declare and work with array in java

Answer (score 0):

There is difference in single variable and arrays of Data types. You have to assign an array like an array .. example..

to assign empty string array

```
String arr[] = {};
```

to define integers

```
int arr[] = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to initialise a `String` variable

```
String empLastName="";
```

This is how to initialise a `String` array variable;

```
String[] empLastName= {""};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do in this example is turn an *array of X* into a singular *X*. To paraphrase Bob Tabor:

Variables can be thought of as "buckets" which hold a value. When you say `String s`, you define a "bucket" s which can hold one String value.

However, an *array* is an entirely different issue. An *array* is a "bucket" which holds *other buckets*. It can be visualized as a line of multiple strings, ex:
"A", "B", "C", "D"...
Et cetera. When defining an array, you need to give it a number of elements to hold; this is unchangeable. An array of five items will *always* hold five items. A standard array declaration goes like this:

```
String[] s = new String[5];
s[1] = "A";
s[2] = "B";
```

et cetera. However, be careful about some other answers saying to define an array with `String[] s = {}` or `= {""}`, because this will give you an array with *only one index*, and when you want to hold more than one item, you need to re-create it anyway.

Further reading: [Arrays Tutorial on Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)